# linq to sql , can not solve big sql statement into linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am trying very hard but cannot reach my result. I am new to linq. What should be the proper linq query for this sql query. Please help me out of this.

```
update Teacher set RemainingCredit = RemainingCredit- Course.Credit
from 
CourseAssignTeacher 
join Course on CourseAssignTeacher.CourseId = Course.Id
join Teacher on CourseAssignTeacher.TeacherId = Teacher.Id
where CourseAssignTeacher.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a query that selects what you want to update, then use a `foreach` loop and [`context.SubmitChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
{
    var toUpdate = from cat in db.CourseAssignTeacher
                   join c in db.Course on cat.CourseId equals c.Id
                   join t in db.Teacher on cat.TeacherId equals t.Id
                   where cat.Id = 1
                   select new { Teacher = t, Course = c, CourseAssignTeacher = cat };
    foreach (var x in toUpdate)
    {
        x.Teacher.RemainingCredit = x.Teacher.RemainingCredit - x.Course.Credit;
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```